# Explode a semicolon string and chunk the parts out of it

Tags: php, arrays, regex, split, php-5.5

What I have is

```
$string = 'one;two;three;four;five;six;seven;eight;nine;ten';
```

What I need to have is:

```
$array = [
   ['one', 'two', 'three'],
   ['four', 'five', 'six'],
   ['seven', 'eight', 'nine'],
   ['ten'],
];
```

Basically the string can have unlimited values.

Comment: Always in groups of three?

Comment: Don't you know PHP has a [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)? Now you do.

Comment: Argg... I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be done with `array_chunk` function:

```
$string = 'one;two;three;four;five;six;seven;eight;nine;ten';
$array = array_chunk(explode(';', $string), 3);
```

Comment: I like it how the question title was the answer in disguise.